# Translate "self-descriptive number"

Tags: single-word-requests, science

I’m looking for a translation of [self-descriptive number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-descriptive_number) and I create "mempriskribanta nombro". Do you think it’s ok? If not, what can I use instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's notice that [other languages choose conceptually similarly constructed names](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1781115) for this type of number. So unless there already is an established term for that in Esperanto (I'm not aware of any, but I'm not a mathematician), Esperanto can probably indeed do the same.

Though, a self-descriptive number doesn't actually perform the *action* of describing itself. (After all, numbers can't talk nor write.) Rather, it seems to be a *property* of such numbers that their representation in a specific base can in a certain way be seen as describing that very representation.

Therefore, I think that

> mempriskriba nombro

is a better fit than "mempriskrib**ant**a nombro". Note that English has the same nuance (descriptive vs. describing) while German for example doesn't (both would be "beschreibend").

Bonus: As Juha [pointed out in a comment](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/5954/translate-self-descriptive-number/5955?noredirect=1#comment6514_5955), "mempriskriba" is shorter and simpler than "mempriskrib**ant**a".

Comment: I would like to add that since there is no need to distinguish between _mempriskriba_ and _mempriskribanta_, let us choose the simpler one.

Answer (score 3):

I didn't find *self-descriptive number* in Esperanto, but I found in PIV [*priskriba geometrio*](http://vortaro.net/#priskriba%20geometrio), matching the English definition for *descriptive geometry*. So I would translate it as ***mempriskriba nombro***.